# treemap for no hierarchical data

Tags: r, data-visualization, treemap

I am new in R. I have a scenario, may be you can give me some hints.

I have a very simple vector:

```
dt<-c(4.94 , 4.84 , 2.89)
```

I would like to have a main square, with the area of 4.94, and then in this area the second square 4.84. Third square with the area of 2.89 should be in the second square (4.84)

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
areas <- c(4.94 , 4.84 , 2.89) #vector of areas
sides <- sqrt(areas) #vectors of side lengths

plot(0,0,type="n",xlim=c(0,4),ylim=c(0,4),axes=F,ann=F, asp=1) #Blank plot
rect(0,0,sides,sides,col=1:3,border=1:3)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

or centered:

```
plot(0,0,type="n",xlim=c(-2,2),ylim=c(-2,2),axes=F,ann=F, asp=1) #Blank plot
rect(-sides/2,-sides/2,sides/2,sides/2,col=1:3,border=1:3)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Is this what your looking for?

Comment: Thank you so much, How can I embed the thirs square? does it possible to have caption for each square?

Comment: There is already 3 squares here (the difference between your first and your second square is very small).